# npm ERR! oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for darwin arm64

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I have this error

```
npm ERR! path /Users/honor/Documents/mycompany/node_modules/oracledb
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node package/install.js
npm ERR! oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for darwin arm64
npm ERR! oracledb ERR! Try compiling node-oracledb source code using https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#github

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/honor/.npm/_logs/2021-11-19T09_09_49_590Z-debug.log
```

My environment is
node v14.18.1
npm v6.14.15
"oracledb": "^4.2.0",
macbook pro 2020 m1

Comment: There is no M1 port of Oracle Instant Client so you need to use an x86 stack (including Node.js) with Rosetta.  See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1349

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For reference, there is a solution on your duplicate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064150/error-dpi-1047-oracle-database-connection-error/70079558#70079558

Comment: it's not working with my apple m1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I installed from binary code and it's work for me
(it depends on your oracledb version)

```
"oracledb": "https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/download/v4.2.0/oracledb-src-4.2.0.tgz"
```

Comment: Use a recent version.  The current version is 5.3

Comment: it's not working with me

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Apple M1 specifically, it is a 'known' issue.

**Below solution worked for me:**
You probably installed node with either nvm or brew, by doing that you will install the arm64 version and get this error. The only solution for now is to download and install node from the homepage directly.

Read below for reference: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1349

Comment: Look at [How to Install node-oracledb 5.5 and Oracle Database on Apple M1/M2 Silicon](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/how-to-install-node-oracledb-5-5-and-oracle-database-on-apple-m1-m2-silicon-941fccda692f).  Also note that the new Thin mode of node-oracledb 6.0 doesn't need Instant Client and runs fine on Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

I also have issues when I work with Oracle. Because node-oracleDb is unsupported for arm64 in version old. You should update the version of node-oracleDB lastest.
after, let's follow to link:
https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-github-clones-and-zip-files
(2.8.1. Installing GitHub Clones and ZIP Files)