# Error: DPI-1047 Oracle Database Connection Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, node-oracledb

I'm trying to connect oracle database with node-oracledb but i have this error.

```
Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (not a mach-o file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/onuryuksekkaya/Documents/done/getwebee-pms/.webpack/service/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (not a mach-o file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file)". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have the arm64 Oracle Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package in ~/lib or /usr/local/lib
They can be downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html
```

Is there a quick solutions for this ?

I'm using node 14.18.1 and oracle 4.2.0 and m1 macbook pro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem like this:

first of all , you have to install node-oracledb from source code.
it has to be like this(it depends on your oracledb version)

```
"oracledb": "https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/download/v5.3.0/oracledb-src-5.3.0.tgz",
```

then you have to download x86 oracle instantclient Basic Package (ZIP) from here : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

then you have to change your node version from `arm` to x86.
you can change it in your zsh terminal with this command

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
```

(you have to install node modules with node x64 version)

if you want to make sure to your node version is x64 you can follow these steps on terminal

`node`
`console.log(process.arch)`

output will be your arch. it has to be x64

when you use these command you will install oracle instant client
`rm /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib`
`ln -s ~/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib /usr/local/lib`

when you try to run your project, output will be permisson error with a document name. You have to open these documents with a text editor, one by one. When you open all these documents, you can run your project freely.